# How to group by product ID with latest creation date in mysql?

Tags: mysql, select

I have select statement as below and sample output :-

```
select uph.creation_date, p.name,p.product_id from product p 
                left join user_product_history uph on p.product_id = uph.product_id 
                where uph.user_id = 124 order by uph.creation_date desc
```

[image]

How can I group by product ID with lastest creation date? Please help. Thank you.

**Edited with PHP API .model file**

```
// ~/user/product_history
    public function product_history($data) {
        $sql = 'select uph.creation_date,
        p.name,
        p.product_id
        from product p
        join user_product_history uph
        on p.product_id = uph.product_id and
        uph.user_id = ?
        join (select product_id,
              MAX(creation_date) AS max_creation_date
              from user_product_history
              where user_id = ?
              group by product_id) dt
        on dt.product_id = uph.product_id and
        dt.max_creation_date = uph.creation_date
        order by uph.creation_date desc';

        $result = $this->db->query($sql, array($data['user_id']));
        $records = array();
        foreach( $result->result_array() as $r ) {
            $r['product_id'] = (int) $r['product_id'];
            $r['sub_category_id'] = (int) $r['sub_category_id'];
            $r['merchant_id'] = (int) $r['merchant_id'];
            if (!isset($r['price_discount'])) $r['price_discount'] = '';
            $records[] = $r;
        }
        return $records;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Firstly, you dont need a `Left Join` here, as you are filtering on `user_product_history` table also. It does seem like you want to show only those product(s), which has a `creation_date` corresponding to `user_id = 124`. So, you can simply use `Inner Join` instead.
- In a derived table (sub-select query), determine the maximum value of `creation_date` for every `product_id`.
- Now, use this result-set to join to the main tables, on `product_id` and the `creation_date`, to get the complete row.

Try the following:

```
select uph.creation_date, 
       p.name,
       p.product_id 
from product p 
join user_product_history uph 
  on p.product_id = uph.product_id and 
     uph.user_id = 124 
join (select product_id, 
             MAX(creation_date) AS max_creation_date
      from user_product_history 
      where user_id = 124 
      group by product_id) dt 
  on dt.product_id = uph.product_id and 
     dt.max_creation_date = uph.creation_date 
order by uph.creation_date desc
```

Comment: thanks for your prompt reply and your answer is works! Abit out of topic, I will using this statement in php API. When I apply this statement and replace 124 to ?, i hit error as below:-`<h1>A Database Error Occurred</h1>
  <p>Error Number: 1064</p><p>You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?
        join (select product_id,
              MAX(creation_date) AS max_creat' at line 7</p><p>select uph.creation_date,` Any idea?

Comment: @henry please share the application code (eg: PHP) you are using to run this query.

Comment: Hi. @Madhur, edited in my post, kindly review. Thanks!

Comment: @henry note that number of `?` has increased now with my query. `user_id` is checked twice now. You should use `array($data['user_id'], $data['user_id'])` instead

Comment: Opps, you are right, I forgot about it, Thanks Madhur!

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
    uph.creation_date, 
    p.name,p.product_id 
from 
    product p 
    left join user_product_history uph on p.product_id = uph.product_id 
where 
    uph.user_id = 124 and
    uph.creation_date = (select
                             max(creation_date)
                         from 
                             user_product_history) 
order by 
    uph.creation_date desc
```

Comment: This will return only one row.

Comment: hi @dwir182, I would like to return more than 1 row result.